# Increase end argument in str_sub up until we get unique values in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my toy data

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~names,
        "apple alpha",
        "grapes beta",
        "orange gamma",
        'graphite alpha',
        "a bc",
        "apple gamma")
```

Here a sample code:

```
df_1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(first_word = word(names),
         first_n_letters = str_sub(names, start = 1L, end = 4L) %>% str_trim(),
         small_name = if_else(nchar(first_word) > nchar(first_n_letters), first_word, first_n_letters))
```

I want to keep increasing the end argument of str_sub in the above code up until the point when

```
n_distinct(df_1 %>% select(small_name)) == nrow(df_1)
```

In other words, the nchar(small_name) should be just big enough so that there are no duplicate small_name in the dataframe.

So, in this case, the iterator in the loop should stop at 7 as that will provide unique values of small_name in the df_1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to just define your own function to do this:

```r
shortest_unique <- function(x)
{
  n_uniq <- sapply(seq(max(nchar(x))), function(y) length(unique(substr(x, 1, y))))
  trimws(substr(x, 1, which.max(n_uniq)))
}

df %>% mutate(first_word = word(names), short_name = shortest_unique(names))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   names          first_word short_name
#>   <chr>          <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1 apple alpha    apple      apple a   
#> 2 grapes beta    grapes     grapes    
#> 3 orange gamma   orange     orange    
#> 4 graphite alpha graphite   graphit   
#> 5 a bc           a          a bc      
#> 6 apple gamma    apple      apple g
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>